# jBPM 5.4 with Tomcat 7 and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7, jbpm

Right now, I'm using JBoss AS 7 server and H2 database (default configuration) for jBPM 5.4, but I want to use Tomcat 7 and MySQL 5+ for it.

I googled it, but I did not found any answer with a step by step explanation like a tutorial. And also there is no official documentation for it.

Does anyone have an idea about the installation and configuration for it? Or does anyone has an idea about how to make Tomcat a full Java EE server like JBoss AS, GlassFish, WebLogic, etc?

Please give me the proper direction or any other way.

Answer (score 2):

> Or does anyone has an idea about how to make Tomcat a full Java EE server like JBoss AS, GlassFish, WebLogic, etc?

You can make Tomcat *almost* a full Java EE 6 server via TomEE. The bits you need can be downloaded [here](http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html). This will make it either a complete Web Profile, or something that's in between the Web Profile and the Full Profile.